# BitmapImage will play GIF animation in an UWP app when TargetDeviceFamily is UNIVERSAL but not DESKTOP?

Tags: uwp, animated-gif

Just spent hours trying to understand why my GIFs stopped playing, until I realized that I had changed the target in Package.appxmanifest from

```
<TargetDeviceFamily Name="Windows.Universal" MinVersion="10.0.0.0" MaxVersionTested="10.0.0.0" />
```

to

```
<TargetDeviceFamily Name="Windows.Desktop" MinVersion="10.0.0.0" MaxVersionTested="10.0.0.0" />
```

I am building a desktop-only app...  No warning during code execution was given, nothing that would have led me to discover the impact of that change.. Why, oh why?

**So what is the correct way to declare the TargetDeviceFamily for a desktop-only UWP app???**

Holy Mother am I annoyed...

Comment: If you make app package for x86 and x64 so it will automatically install on pc and if you choose arm it will install also on mobiles, and further at the time of publishing app you will be ask for supported device then mark only desktop , so only desktop user can able to download this

Comment: Further you can mark app for desktop , can you show some code so i can check and provide solution

Comment: I know that. What I am rather unhappy with is that when I choose Desktop as the target, seemingly a whole lot of features disappear, like mentioned GIF animation. Why is that? Why does that make any sense? Desktop should be the most powerful platform, with maybe Location and other mobile features not present. To turn off GIF animation is just mental.

Comment: Okay wait let me check in my machine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this is solution for you i had tested in windows 10.0.15063 sdk
follow this steps :

1)

```
<TargetDeviceFamily Name="Windows.Desktop" MinVersion="10.0.15063.0" MaxVersionTested="10.0.15063.0" />
```

2) Then goto Reference and right click on it and then click on "Add refernece".

3) Then in Extensions add respective uwp desktop extension (as shown in screenshot).

[image: Screenshot]

4) Now Build and Debug your "gif" will be start animating.

:)

Comment: Is it ok if I say "Oh The Humanity"...?  Thank you for all the effort!

Comment: Is it worked or not ?, it should because i already tested both case in my machine. If It it is worked you can mark this as answer ;)

Comment: Hi Shubham, am a bit under the gun to ship code to testing. Right now, I build to UNIVERSAL rather than DESKTOP, since I do not know what other features might disappear and I do not understand the advantage of building to DESKTOP (other than that folks cannot get the app for other platforms)... Will verify over the weekend. THANKS

Comment: Okay   but after adding extension everything will go fine and further yes there may be difference in availability of api if target specific device

Comment: I have now worked with UWP for more than a year and would not dare to use the line "everything will go fine..."

Comment: I confirm that the animation is now playing. I had to lower the build to 10.0.14393.0, since that is the current platform. I am still very hesitant to deploy this hot, as I do not understand what other features the change to DESKTOP is omitting...  Thank you Shubham, well done!

Comment: Yes you can continue, no much differences